# Jquery Ajax autocomplete not firing for some users

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a site I'm in which some users' autocomplete is not firing in some instances of IE 11.  For other users on different machines, it is.  Its in development so I can test these cases locally on different dev's machines.  In fiddler, when it is not working, the request doesn't even fire, so its not like its requesting and failing.  I tried tweaking internet options in IE to no avail.  Disabled addons, trusted local sites.

Heres the code that works on some IE instances

```
$("#prodSearch").autocomplete({
  minLength: 2,
  source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/home/SearchProductCodeAutoComplete", type: "Post", dataType: "json",
      data: {
        searchText: request.term,
        maxResults: 15
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data, function (item) {
        return {
          label: item.ID + ' - ' + item.Description,
          value: item.ID, id: item.ID
        }
      }))
    }
  })
  },
  select: function (event, ui) {           
    //do stuff
  }
});
```

I've tried both Get and Post, no cache in controller